# Return FileName Only when using OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following method to browse for a file:

```
    OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    PictureNameTextEdit.Text = OpenFileDialog.FileName
```

Is there a way get ONLY the file name?

The **FileName** method returns the entire path and file name.

i.e. I want Foo.txt instead of C:\SomeDirectory\Foo.txt

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetFileName(fullPath)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to get just the filename part, like this:

```
OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
PictureNameTextEdit.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
PictureNameTextEdit.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
```

Comment: Why downvoting? This is correct sample code for OP's question. I included this information as part of Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 1):

C++ code for obtain filename and complete path in OpenFileDialog:

`textBox1->Text = OpenFileDialog1->FileName; //complete path
textBox1->Text = System::IO::Path::GetFileName(OpenFileDialog1->FileName);  //filename`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that I did select word2010 file named as "MyFileName.docx"

This is for ONLY the selected file extension "including the dot mark, f.e (.docx)"

```
MsgBox(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Opendlg.FileName))
```

And this for the selected File name without extension: (MyFileName)

```
MsgBox(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Opendlg.FileName))
```

and you can try the other options for the "PATH Class" like: GetFullPath,GetDirectoryName ...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

if you want just the selected name without Extension you can try this code

```
Imports System.IO


PictureNameTextEdit.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OpenFileDialog1.Fi‌​leName)
```

thanx

Answer (score -1):

```
//Following code return file name only 

string[] FileFullPath;
string FileName;
objOpenFileDialog.Title = "Select Center Logo";
objOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog();

FileFullPath = objOpenFileDialog.FileNames[0].ToString().Split('\\');
FileName = FileFullPath[FileFullPath.Length - 1]; //return only File Name

//Use following code if u want save other folder , 
// following code save file to CenterLogo  folder which inside bin folder//

System.IO.File.Copy(OFD.FileName, Application.StartupPath + 
"/CenterLogo/" + FileName, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use SafeFileName instead of FileName and it will return a name (and extension) without path.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to put the filename in PictureNameTextEdit:

```
OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
PictureNameTextEdit.Text = OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName
```