# Visual Basic not recognizing Path.GetFileName Method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am following this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342268/return-filename-only-when-using-openfiledialog) in trying to get the filename in my Visual Basic application.  When I start to type 'Path', the Visual Studio 2010 IDE does not recognize Path.GetFileName.  How do I get Visual Studio 2010 to recognize the Path.GetFIleName method?

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx#Y0) is the official Microsoft page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you're not referencing the System.IO namespace?  If you type System.IO.Path.   does it then work?  If so, keep that, or add Imports System.IO to the top of your file.

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim x As String = Path.GetFileName("")

    End Sub

End Module
```