# VB.NET 2008 Not recognizing Path.GetFileName Method

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have read this post but nothing works.
[Visual Basic not recognizing Path.GetFileName Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907264/visual-basic-not-recognizing-path-getfilename-method)
I am following this page in trying to get the filename in my Visual Basic application but i can't compile it [Microsoft Official Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx#Y0)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    size_mode_list.Items.AddRange([Enum].GetNames(GetType(PictureBoxSizeMode)))


    For Each drive As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives
        Dim node As TreeNode = _
            file_view_tree.Nodes.Add(drive.Name)
        node.Tag = ItemType.Drive
        node.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub file_view_tree_BeforeExpand(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles file_view_tree.BeforeExpand
    Dim currentNode As TreeNode = e.Node
    currentNode.Nodes.Clear()
    Try
        'Now go get all the files and folders
        Dim fullPathString As String = currentNode.FullPath

        'Handle each folder
        For Each dolderString As String In _
            Directory.GetDirectories(fullPathString)
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = _
                currentNode.Nodes.Add(path.getFileName(folderString))
            Dim x As String = path.GetFileName("")
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.Folder
            newNode.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
        Next

        'Handle each file
        For Each fileString As String In _
            Directory.GetFiles(fullPathString)
            'Get just the file name portion (without the path) :
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = _
                currentNode.Nodes.Add(path.getFileName(fileString))
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.File
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesnt look like you followed the remedy/answer for the first link. specifically, add `Imports System.IO` to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Don't forget to import this
Imports System.IO

'Declare these
Private Enum ItemType
    Drive
    Folder
    File
End Enum

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each drive As DriveInfo In DriveInfo.GetDrives
        Dim node As TreeNode = _
            file_view_tree.Nodes.Add(drive.Name)
        node.Tag = ItemType.Drive
        node.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub file_view_tree_BeforeExpand(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventArgs) Handles file_view_tree.BeforeExpand
    Dim currentNode As TreeNode = e.Node
    currentNode.Nodes.Clear()
    Try
        'Now go get all the files and folders
        Dim fullPathString As String = currentNode.FullPath

        'Handle each folder
        For Each folderString As String In _
            Directory.GetDirectories(fullPathString)
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = _
            currentNode.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(folderString))
            Dim x As String = Path.GetFileName("")
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.Folder
            newNode.Nodes.Add("FILLER")
        Next

        'Handle each file
        For Each fileString As String In _
            Directory.GetFiles(fullPathString)
            'Get just the file name portion (without the path) :
            Dim newNode As TreeNode = _
            currentNode.Nodes.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileString))
            newNode.Tag = ItemType.File
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```